# Kivy does not find fonts in Cygwin

Tags: python, fonts, cygwin, kivy, x11

I use `Kivy` in `Cygwin.`

Per **Vasilkov, Mark. *Kivy Blueprints*. Birmingham:Packt Publishing, 2015. pp. 17**, I wanted to use the `Roboto` fonts in the following code:

```
# File: main.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

LabelBase.register(name='Roboto',
        fn_regular='Roboto-Thin.ttf',
        fn_bold='Roboto-Medium.ttf')

class ClockApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClockApp().run()
```

However, even though `Cygwin` is aware that the `Roboto` fonts are installed in `/usr/share/fonts/,` viz.:

```
$ fc-list | grep -i robot
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf: Roboto:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf: Roboto,Roboto Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf: Roboto:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf: Roboto,Roboto Medium:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf: Roboto,Roboto Thin:style=Thin Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/RobotoCondensed-Italic.ttf: Roboto Condensed:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf: Roboto:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Black.ttf: Roboto,Roboto Black:style=Black,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/RobotoCondensed-LightItalic.ttf: Roboto Condensed,Roboto Condensed Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf: Roboto,Roboto Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf: Roboto Condensed:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf: Roboto:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/RobotoCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf: Roboto Condensed:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf: Roboto Condensed,Roboto Condensed Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf: Roboto Condensed:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf: Roboto,Roboto Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf: Roboto,Roboto Thin:style=Thin,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf: Roboto,Roboto Black:style=Black Italic,Italic
```

when I run the above Python code, I get:

```
$ python main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/Administrator/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-10-09_18.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.10 (default, Jun  1 2015, 18:17:45)
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
     fn_bold='Roboto-Medium.ttf')
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/text/__init__.py", line 223, in register
     raise IOError('File {0}s not found'.format(font_type))
 IOError: File Roboto-Thin.ttfs not found
```

### What should I do to let `Kivy` use the `Roboto` fonts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the path of your fonts in your `LabelBase.register()`. Do you have those font files in your directory?